# dockerでWindows以外のDockerホストに対してDockerイメージを構築すると、セキュリティ警告が表示される

Tags: windows, docker

Dockertoolboxを使用して「[Docker超入門⑤〜Dockerfileを使う〜【初心者向け】」](https://datawokagaku.com/howtousedockerfile/)


でdockerfileを作成しビルドするということをやっていました。

ブログの方はmac版で~/Desktop にdockerというディレクトリを作りそこにdockerfileを作成していたみたいです。私はwindowsでdockertoolboxを使用していることもあり、なるべくデフォルトのディレクトリで進めようとしていたのですがデフォルトの/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox下で`mkdir docker`としようとするとパーミッションエラーが出ます。

そこで不安ながらも`/c/Desktop`下にdockerディレクトリ作成し、その中でdockerfileを作成し`docker build`したところ以下のメッセージが出ました。セキュリティの問題らしいことはわかるのですが、このまま進めても特に問題ないでしょうか？また、Docker Quickstart Terminalを起動したときにいるデフォルトのディレクトリ`/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox`ではパーミッションdeniedされ、下手に変更していいものか悩んでいます。やはりこのディレクトリ下で作業できるようにしたほうが良いのでしょうか？

```
 You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Comment: 同件？ [dockerでWindows以外のDockerホストに対してDockerイメージを構築すると、セキュリティ警告が表示される](https://teratail.com/questions/241907), 類似？ [Docker Toolboxのパーミッション変更](https://teratail.com/questions/248253), まあ気にしないで良いのかもしれません。 [DockerでPythonの環境構築を行う（Windows10 Home編）](https://blauthree.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/07/27/233448), [Windowsで構成情報をDockerfileに定義してイメージを作成してみる](https://qiita.com/fkooo/items/53b2ea865e8c2c7fec27), [Docker for Windows、Dockerfileを試してみる](https://blog.naichilab.com/entry/dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

**1点目**

`C:\Program Files\` 以下には通常だと管理者権限が無いと書き込みができないためエラーになっています。
`Program Files` のアクセス権を変更してしまうのも一つの方法ではありますが、安全のためには (書き込み権限のある) 別のフォルダを用意して作業することをおすすめします。

**2点目**

`You are building a Docker image ...` の警告メッセージは「作成されるファイルが一律 `-rwxr-xr-x` = 誰でも読み取り権限のある状態で作成されるので、必要に応じて修正してください」といった内容です。

PCを共有して利用しているような場合、Cドライブ直下などに今回の Docker コンテナ関連のファイルを置くと、別のユーザも閲覧可能な状態になります。
適切にアクセス権を修正するか、PCを個人で利用している場合には特に気にしなくても大丈夫です。

Comment: デフォルトでは/c/Program Files/Docker Toolboxにいるのですが、Docker Toolboxにいる意味は特になく、別のディレクトリで自由に作業できるということなのですね。

グループ所有者はPCのフォルダやディレクトリを共有するときなどに問題になるのですね。今まで個人でやってきていたのでおっしゃる通り大丈夫そうです。